# Mass removing CSS from 1,700 post

Tags: post-meta, post-editor, blogger

I just migrated from blogger to wordpress and I have over 1,700 post with this line of css in them

.alignleft {
 float: left;
}

.alignright {
 float: right;
}

Along with some meta which shows up in wordpress post is there a way to mass edit the post and remove or hide this?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove them by replacing the line( .alignleft { float: left; } ) with empty space in database ( but you should avoid using SQL query). Make sure you have back up before trying anything.

There is a php script  which i used for replacing my loclahost url to live site url while migrating wordpress site from local machine to live server. You can try this script( [serach and replace script by interconnectit.com](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)) to find the occurences of css class and replace with them empty space.

This script also provide dry run  option so you can review the change before applying them. This script is reputed and used by many developers. you can find reference from tuts-plus here.[tuts+](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/migrating-wordpress-across-hosts-servers-and-urls--wp-20104)